# Able to add objects to NSMutableDictionary, but trying to access objects gives 'unrecognized selector' error

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

I'm using ARC, and I'm almost certain this is a memory related issue.

I have several classes: `DiningHall`, `Meal`, and `Station`.  `DiningHalls` store various `meals` using a mutable dictionary, and each `meal` stores various `stations` using another mutable dictionary.  When I try to access a `station` from the `meal's` stationList property, I get the following error:

Below is the code I tested to debug:  before I add a new station to the dictionary, I tried listing the dictionary's existing contents, giving me the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Inside DiningHall class:

```
- (void) addStation:(Station*)s toMeal:(NSString*) mealType {

     Meal *m = [self.mealList objectForKey:mealType];
    NSArray* a = [m.stationList allKeys];
    for (Station* s in a)
        NSLog(@"%@", s.name); //line generating error
    [m addStation:s];

}
```

Inside Meal class:

```
- (void)addStation:(Station *)station {

    [self.stationList setObject:station forKey:station.name];
   //also tried  [self.stationList setValue:station forKey:station.name];
}
```

In init of meal class:

```
self.stationList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

The reason I think this is a problem with the dictionary is that when I replaced the `stationList` dictionary with a mutable array, (and adjusted the test code appropriately), it did not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is in this line of code:

```
NSArray* a = [m.stationList allKeys];
for (Station* s in a)
     NSLog(@"%@", s.name); //line generating error
```

Because the array `a` contain the key and the value of the dictionary. And since you set the key of the dicionary to `station.name` array `a` only contains strings and not atations.

Try:

```
NSArray* a = [m.stationList allValues];
for (Station* s in a)
     NSLog(@"%@", s.name); //line generating error
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the station.name as key:

```
[self.stationList setObject:station forKey:station.name];
```

And then you try to access the station object when iterating over all keys:

```
for (Station* s in a)
    NSLog(@"%@", s.name);
```

But the keys will only give the station names. You want

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.stationList objectForKey:s]);
```